# How to add ForceAuthn flag on AWS cognito

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml, service-provider, idp

I'm using AWS cognito as SP while using SAML with other Idps. I want for specific customer to use ForceAuthn to enforce login in every authentication. How can I do that with AWS cognito?
And could it be set for specific integrations into the user pool or have to be set for all of them?

Till now I checked in the documentation and support center. I didn't found option to do that, I saw that 3 months ago they updated other user that it is not supported yet, but hope they added it or there's a work around

Thanks!